# variable out of scope with extension

Tags: swift

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var str = "You tapped me"
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

---

```
extension UIViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(str)
    }
}
```

Comment: `str` has been created in `ViewController`. You have to extend the subclass, delete `UI`

Comment: omg thank you @vadian! :) 
I was very blind at this point...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @vadian. Make the following code updates and this should resolve the issue unless I am missing something else.

Current Code:

```
extension UIViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(str)
    }
}
```

Updated Code:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(str)
    }
```

Second Example: Here is an additional example on using extension on a class:

//Declaration on Lamborghini Class:

```
class Lamborghini: UIImage {
    var didTapButton = "Congrats button tapped!"
}
```

//Extension on Lamborghini Class:

```
extension Lamborghini: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print(didTapButton)
    }
}
```

Notice that when declaring an extension the Name of the class extended is what follows the extension keyword. Then to the right of the colon the type of class, protocol etc is added.

```
extension ClassNameHere: SuperClassHere, ProtocolHere { }
```

Check out the swift documentation on extensions here at [Swift Extensions](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html)

Hope this helps resolve the issue.

Comment: also thanks for your help and the explanation :)
I'm pretty new to swift right now.

Comment: @Shizzle Anytime! Unfortunately you will find many on stackoverflow don't give thorough explanations nor code based explanations. Thats one challenge with the community. I am trying to be apart of that change and provide code based explanations with helpful links to related information. Have fun coding Shizzle